# Change way of highlight selected rows in DataGrid with styled cells

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I'm creating WPF App and I'm using `DataGrid`. The problem is after I styled `DataGridCell` to have margins and alignment in every cell, selection only highlights the background behind text, not all cells.

Something like this:

[image]

Code behind styling:

```
            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8,0,8,0"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

How to prevent it? There is some way to do it?\

Edit: I reproduce it on clean project without problems, all code of example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="grid" Margin="10">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="0.2*" Binding="{Binding first_name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Width="0.2*" Binding="{Binding last_name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="E-mail" Width="0.2*" Binding="{Binding email}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone number" Width="0.2*" Binding="{Binding phone}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8,0,8,0"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Class of that xaml:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Client client = new Client();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            client = new Client()
            {
                first_name = "John",
                last_name = "Connor",
                email = "john_connor@mail.com",
                phone = "123456789"
            };

            this.grid.DataContext = client;
            this.grid.Items.Add(client);
        }
    }

    public class Client
    {
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably, by defining the `RowStyle`. Btw, can you share the complete xaml sample?

Comment: I can't, but I tried this styles on fresh DataGrid and unfortunately no difference, so posting all xaml don't change anything.

Comment: What are the other styles in your `DataGrid`? This issue is not reproducible using the `CellStyle` you have given.

Comment: @Aakanksha I edited my post with example of xaml with issue.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I edited my post with example of xaml with issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that `Margin` makes problems. So try to get rid of `Margin` if you can.
If not, I'm afraid you have to override the default control template to change the `DataGrid`'s behavior and have a clean solution. As work around you could change a color of the selected row, but if the `DataGrid` lost focus it will be ugly again.

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8,0,8,0"/>
    </Style>                
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

I would also use `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` instead of `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment`.

E.g. you could also use `DataGridTemplateColumn` instead of `DataGridTextColumn` and put `Margin` to the control in `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding first_name}" Margin="8,0,8,0"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                    
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <!--Other columns-->
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Using `HorizontalContentAlignment`, `VerticalContentAlignment` and getting rid of `Margin` fixed problem, thank you. There is some alternative to `Margin` I could use?

Comment: @GhostVolume I have extended the answer.